# Equivalence Relations, Partitions and Equivalence Classes

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

Consider the partition P={{0},{−1,1},{−2,2},{−3,3},{−4,4},...} of Z. Describe the equivalence relation whose equivalence classes are the elements of P. I'm struggling to grasp what the question is asking and how to go about solving it.

Comment: In everyday language... it is asking "*What is it that makes $1$ and $-1$ 'alike' in the same way that $2$ and $-2$ are 'alike' and $3$ and $-3$ 'alike' and $0$ unlike anything else?*"  What does it mean to be "alike" in this context?

Comment: $x\sim y\iff x=\pm y$. And you'll get $\mathbb Z/_\sim\cong \mathbb N$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** What are the equivalence classes of the relation $\sim$ on $\mathbb Z$ defined by $x\sim y$ if and only if $x=\pm y$?

Answer (score 0):

Given a set $A$ and a partition $P \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$ of $A$, define the relation $x \sim y$ if and only if $x$ and $y$ belongs to the same element of $P$, for all $x$ and $y$ in $A$. This is defined for all elements of $A$ since $P$ "covers" $A$, and you need to verify that this is an equivalence relation using the properties of a partition.

Comment: Oh so would a reasonable answer be "xRy if and only if x=±y for all x and y in Z"?

Comment: An element of $P$ in your case is of the form $\{-k,k\}$ for some integer $k$. According to my answer, you need to define $x \sim y$ if and only if $x,y \in \{-k,k\}$ for some integer $k$, but this is precisely as saying that $x = y$ or $x=-y$. My answer is a more general recipe.

Answer (score 0):

Given two sets $X$, $Y$ and a function $f:\>X\to Y$ the setting
$$x\sim x'\quad:\Leftrightarrow\quad f(x)=f(x')$$
defines an equivalence relation on $X$: Two points $x$, $x'\in X$ are *equivalent* if $f$ assumes the same value in the two points.

In the case at hand the base set is ${\mathbb Z}$, and as $f$ you can take $f(x):=x^2$. Two integers are *equivalent* if their squares agree. The different values of $f$ are $0$, $1$, $4$, $9$, $\ldots$, and to each such value corresponds an equivalence class $\{0\}$, $\{-1,1\}$, $\{-2,2\}$,$\{-3,3\}$, $\ldots\ $ .

Answer (score -1):

Consider set of integers $\Bbb Z$ With given any partition p then $x=\pm y$ if and only if {${x,y}$} $\in$ P

Comment: I would rather say : $\{x,y\}\in P$.

Comment: i edited that answer